# Strange Double Logging in Singleton Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, singleton, slf4j

I have this code:

```
public enum Something {
    INSTANCE;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Something.class);

    private Something() {
        Thread testThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something
                LOGGER.info("TESTTHREAD: This should only appear once!");
            }
        });
        testThread.setName("TestThread");
        testThread.start();
    }
}
```

and when I run

```
Something.INSTANCE.getClass();
```

what gets logged (with the exact same timestamps) is:

```
TESTTHREAD: This should only appear once!
TESTTHREAD: This should only appear once!
```

Has anyone ever seen anything like this, or know what could be going on?

Comment: Yeah, show us your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is the result of appender additivity. I'm assuming you have a ROOT logger with an `appender-ref` and a separate logger (for your class) also with an `appender-ref`. Appenders are inherited by default, so any log statements sent through your child logger will go the child's appenders and the parent's appenders. What you want to do is disable this by setting the `additivity` attribute of your child logger to `false`.

Comment: This was it! I had an overriding logger appender for this class without the additivity attribute - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I run this

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    enum Singleton {
        INSTANCE;

        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Singleton.class.getName());

        Singleton() {
            Thread testThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    LOGGER.info("Print only once");
                }
            });
            testThread.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        Singleton.INSTANCE.toString();
    }
}
```

I only get

```
Jun 05, 2014 10:03:08 AM Main$Singleton$1 run
INFO: Print only once
```

Comment: I'm using org.slf4j.Logger & org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Comment: @mathematician You might also want to specify which implementation. Logback?